# htmx hx-trigger: Don't work with two triggers

Tags: javascript, htmx

I have an element `span` for infinite scroll:

```
{# it is last row of table #}

  {% if paginator.has_next and forloop.last %}
     <span id='triggerElement'
         hx-get="{% url 'api' %}?page={{ paginator.next_page_number }}"
         hx-swap="beforeend"
         hx-target="#loop"
         hx-select=".htmx-scroll"
         hx-trigger="revealed, loadMore">
      </span>
    {% endif %}
  </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

and it work fine.

Then, I want to trigger this element manually, with some javascript code:

```
function triggerUpdate() {
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.htmx-scroll');
    const count = elements.length;
    if (count < 3) {
        document.body.dispatchEvent(new Event('loadMore'));
    }
}
```

And add event `loadMore` to `hx-trigger`:

```
<span id='triggerElement'
      hx-get="{% url 'api' %}?page={{ page.next_page_number }}"
      hx-swap="beforeend"
      hx-target="#loop"
      hx-select=".htmx-scroll"
      hx-trigger="revealed, loadMore from:body">
</span>
```

And now infinite scrolling not working! When `loadMore` fire, it perform request and update DOM properly, but nothing happens on `revealed` event.

`Revealed` just stop working if I add something dummy as `hx-trigger="revealed, abcd">`

Look as something wrong with combine `revealed` with any other event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have problems with a combination of these elements, try using `hx-trigger` separately for evened and `loadMore` for different elements.

```
<span id='triggerElement'
  hx-get="{% url 'api' %}?page={{ page.next_page_number }}"
  hx-swap="beforeend"
  hx-target="#loop"
  hx-select=".htmx-scroll"
  hx-trigger="revealed">
</span>

<span id='triggerElementForManual'
  hx-trigger="loadMore"
  style="display:none;">
</span>
```

Then, if you want to manually trigger the `loadMore` event in JavaScript, do this:

```
function triggerUpdate() {
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.htmx-scroll');
    const count = elements.length;
    if (count < 3) {
        document.getElementById('triggerElementForManual').click(); // Manually trigger loadMore event
    }
}
```